# Undo tag that's not pushed in Git

Tags: git, tags, undo, revert

I've made a commit and a tag (using git tag -a  -m ). I found out before I pushed that I needed to revert the commit so I used `git revert --soft HEAD~`. How do I also remove the tag? I've checked with `git push --tags --dry-run` that it hasn't been pushed yet, so I hope it's possible to remove.

Comment: There is no `--soft` flag for `git revert`. Did you mean `git reset`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just run the following command from the branch where you created the tag:

```
git tag -d <tag name>
```

Even if you pushed the tag already it is still possible to remove it.  Check out this useful [blog post](https://matoski.com/article/git-delete-remote-branch-tag/).

Comment: In case that (very helpful) blog post goes away, the syntax for deleting the remote tag is: `git push origin :refs/tags/<tag name>`